# Android ListView Customization (title, description, details, footer)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

As I'm new to Android, I'm struggling to design a custom layout which is going to be my listview row. I like my list view row should contain title description, details and footer. My listview row hold data like the image I attached. Please see the attached image [image: listView to Implement]

Comment: Is footer, footer of linked list or footer of cell?

Comment: @NinjaCoder footer holds date and time of the respective row

Comment: @Vrangle What have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must need to create your_layout_row.xml first

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="60dp"
 android:orientation="horizontal"
 android:layout_margin="14dp" 
>
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
         >
        <ImageView
     android:id="@+id/imageView"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:paddingLeft="10dp"
     android:layout_height="60dp"
     />
    </LinearLayout>


 <TextView
     android:gravity="center_vertical"
     android:paddingBottom="10dp"
     android:paddingRight="5dp"
     android:id="@+id/textView"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="60dp"
     android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
     android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
     android:text="TextView"
     android:textStyle="normal|italic"
     android:textSize="17dp" />


</LinearLayout>
```

now here you have your listview layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/TaskList_layout_background_color"
    >



                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/lv_list"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"

                    android:dividerHeight="10dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                   android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:paddingRight="10dp"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp" >
                </ListView>



</RelativeLayout>
```

now create your class Model

for example :

```
class ModelClass
{
String text;

public ModelClass(String _text)
{
text =  _text;
}

public String getText()
{
return this.text;
}

}
```

now create your custom adapter class

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ModelClass> {

    // declaring our ArrayList of items
    private ArrayList<ModelClass> objects;

    /* here we must override the constructor for ArrayAdapter
    * the only variable we care about now is ArrayList<Item> objects,
    * because it is the list of objects we want to display.
    */
    public CustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<ModelClass> objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        this.objects = objects;
    }

    /*
     * we are overriding the getView method here - this is what defines how each
     * list item will look.
     */
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

        // assign the view we are converting to a local variable
        View v = convertView;

        // first check to see if the view is null. if so, we have to inflate it.
        // to inflate it basically means to render, or show, the view.
        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout_row null);
        }

        /*
         * Recall that the variable position is sent in as an argument to this method.
         * The variable simply refers to the position of the current object in the list. (The ArrayAdapter
         * iterates through the list we sent it)
         * 
         * Therefore, i refers to the current Item object.
         */
        ModelClass i = objects.get(position);

        if (i != null) {

            // This is how you obtain a reference to the TextViews.
            // These TextViews are created in the XML files we defined.

            TextView tt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView);


            // check to see if each individual textview is null.
            // if not, assign some text!


            if (tt != null){
                tt.setText( objects.get(position).getText());
            }

        }

        // the view must be returned to our activity
        return v;

    }

}
```

now in your main activity set your listview adapter to this customAdapter.

```
ArrayList<MyModel> myList = new new ArrayList<MyModel>();
myList.add("1");
myList.add("2");
myList.add("3");
myList.add("4");
ListView myListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv_list);
CustomAdapter adapter= new CustomAdapter(acitivity, 0, myList);

myListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you have to custom adapter.

Actually Relative is more suitable for designs. But now I'll write with LinearLayout to be easy.

here is the custom layout for listview item...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout                 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"     android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:text="Title"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
        android:gravity="center"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"    
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
            android:text="DESC"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
            android:text="Other Detais"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:text="Footer"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
        android:gravity="center"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

copy and modify above answer by **Hein Htet Aung**

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
       android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:text="Title"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
    android:gravity="center"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"    
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
        android:text="DESC"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
        android:text="Other Detais"/>

    </LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="15dp"
    android:text="Footer"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
    android:gravity="center"/>
```